# dislocker: fuse: mountpoint is not empty

Tags: linux, mount, bitlocker, fstab

I'm setting up a bitlocker drive in Linux fstab:

```
/dev/sdb2                                       /mnt/lacie      fuse.dislocker  user-password=abc123 0 0
/mnt/lacie/dislocker-file                       /mnt/orange     auto nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=C:  0  0
```

then: `sudo mount -a`

success! That's great!

But if I do it again: `sudo mount -a`

```
fuse: mountpoint is not empty
fuse: if you are sure this is safe, use the 'nonempty' mount option
```

That's wierd, I've never seen Linux's fstab system get upset about doing `mount -a` a second time. Sure I could add the "nonempty" option, but the reality is the mount point was empty when first mounted. It just seems to be trying to  remount what is already mounted and getting confused. Why would it try to remount what is already mounted, and am I doing something wrong?